# return from servlet to jsp to specific id in index page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on java servlet project 
I have index.jsp page that take input from user and send it withe post method to readXml servlet page that process the input then return the result to index.jsp

I wont to return to specific id in index.jsp

I used this code for foreword response to index.jsp

```
 request.setAttribute("message", span );
  request.setAttribute("Sent", input );

  request.getRequestDispatcher("/indexjsp.jsp#color").forward(request, response);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/indexjsp.jsp#color").forward(request, response);
```

when I use this code I get resource error

and when I remove #color it will  return the response to index.jsp but not with id I wont.

are there any way to return to specific id from servlet?

Comment: You could just skip the requestdispatcher and send a raw 302 redirect, or maybe set a request parameter and have some js or something to get the parameter in the page and set the id to that after the request is forwarded

Answer (score 0):

DO it something like this

instead of using `#color` try `?id=color`.

Populate this parameter in the hidden input tag on 'index.jsp'. Now you have your tag id on client side. you can do what you want using javascript after onload event triggers.